# How do I make sure my variable is evaluated before the api call?

Tags: api, react-native, axios

I am calling an API and passing in some dynamic variables. All the dynamic variables are evaluated and saved the right way when the api is called, except the **ownerName** called . Below is my function:

```
_onPressRegister() {
  const { latitude, longitude } = this.props;
  const { city, phone, country } = this.state;
  const ownerName = `${this.state.firstName} `${this.state.lastName}`';
 axios.post('http://sewoa-easy-breezy-home-number-api-us1.smx.online/api/v1/houses/registration', { house: { owner_name: ownerName,
       latitude: latitude,
       longitude: longitude,
       telephone: phone,
       city: city,
       location_summary: '',
       country: country
 } }).then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
   if (response.data.number) {
     Actions.viewHouseNumber({ houseNumber: response.data.number });
   }
 })
 .catch((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made, but the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx

      this.setState({ error: error.response.data });

      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
      this.setState({ error: error.message });
    }
    console.log(error.config);
});
 }
```

When the **api** executes the post, the **owner_name** is not evaluated . Instead it is saved as in the database as the exact way it was written.

```
`${this.state.firstName} `${this.state.lastName}`'
```

I have been struggling for a while this. Can anybody help me with this. 
PS: Also when I try to do a simple concatenation with a '+' sign , the api call does not go through.
Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Why/how does API call not go through when using +?

Comment: I do not really know. It 's very weird